# Show saved images in gallery

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am storing images to a particular folder, but the images are not showing in gallery.

```
 val wrapper = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)
            val folder = File(
                wrapper.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
                "FolderName"
            )
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs()
            }
            try {
                val filename = File(folder, "$timeStamp.jpeg")
                val out: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(filename)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
                out.flush()
                out.close()
            }catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

How to show images in the gallery?

Comment: The gallery will never show files from getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: So, how to show images in gallery..?

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory() if you are below Q.

Comment: Or use .insert() using MediaStore. Strange you never reacted on my earlier suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63429815/save-image-to-specific-directory-in-gallery-android

Comment: sorry blackapps....Iam very new to android...how do i use .insert() using MediaStore.

Comment: Repeat: `See stackoverflow pages tagged mediastore. `.